# 'Basic electronics' resources

Tags: hardware

I've seen that there are many resources on programming basis for arduino for people that have some electronics basis or background. Are there similar resources on the opposite? Basics electronics for programmers? Things that cover:

- How to read schematics (different elements that appear there)
- What different pins are used for (yeah, even on a more basic level than [arduino documentation](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Board#.UzSV3WR5NUk))
- General idea of how a protoboard/protoshield works and how to connect components
- General common components (resitors, capacitors...) and when and how to use them...
- Safety rules, what happens when you do something wrong

Comment: Hi, this question is way too broad for this site. In fact, it's really 5 very broad questions in one. If you could re-word questions to make them more specific they would be a better fit for our Q & A format.

Comment: I'm asking for a colection of links/books con the topic. Thought. There's no specific cuestión but i thought it would be nice to have it posted here for future newcommers. If it's not appropiate I can deleite it.

Comment: no need to delete. These kinds of questions, while very useful, are difficult to manage. Something like this could turn into a never ending post with hundreds of edits and comments. That's just not what this site is for.

Answer (score 2):

## From zero to Arduino (maybe a HOWTO someday?)

Rule zero:

- Don't overestimate the other Arduino users! They all were not born with this knowledge too.
- Never be too shy to ask!
- Making mistakes is ok as long as they trigger learning.

(-: short break :-)

You'll find lots of HOWTOs and other tutorials in the wild wild web.

I assume, the confusing thing is to read them in the wrong order.

Forget your Arduino(s) for a while and start with reading about:

- General common components (resitors, capacitors...) and when and how to use them...

This will at least partially answer:

- Safety rules, what happens when you do something wrong
- How to read schematics (different elements that appear there)

If not already done:

- Read about ANDs, ORs, NANDs, NORs, FLIPFLOPs...

This will show how their schematic symbols look like.

- ...compare them to creating the same behaviour by programming (if,
  and (&&), or (||), ...)
- Have a look at bit operations (&, |, ... on whole number variables.

The programming up to this point can be done on your PC.

After this, dedust your Arduino again and jump into:

- What different pins are used for (yeah, even on a more basic level
  than arduino documentation)

(Happy end. At least for now.)

(I make this a community wiki answer to invite others to expand this text.)

Comment: Well making mistakes in electronics can cost a lot: from a few bucks to your life!

Comment: Yes... the dangerous mistakes should be avoided... but when turning a logic chip into magic smoke and then learning why this happened at least was a honourable dead for that chip. And to avoid the most dangerous mistakes, you can power your Arduino by a battery pack and keep it far away of 120V/240V power lines... at least in the beginning...

Comment: @jfpoilpret When applying for the Darwin awards (what I have seen done on Arduino.EE couple times already) does not obey yeti's rule #0 sub 3:  "Making mistakes is ok as long as they trigger learning."

Comment: mmm, should we open showcase thread on arduino darwin awards? could be funny, and illustrative too :p

Comment: Instead of joking arround, you could have improved the answer. That's what wiki is desiged for...

Answer (score 1):

This is an extract of an [introductory book](http://m.dummies.com/DummiesArticle/Arduino-Projects-For-Dummies-Cheat-Sheet.id-379124.html) that shows basic schematic  components: 
[image: Basic schematic components]

Comment: Hi, please add more information to your answer. Link-only answers are discouraged as it becomes useless if the link target changes or gets removed.

Comment: @sachleen -- As of now, the link is dead.